# Loading HTML elements using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to install custom [MailChimp form](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/determine-webpage-signup-location?&_ga=1.91556442.1342248869.1397002825) with hidden fields.
The values that I want to pass on are included in the URL and I extract them using JS. No issue there.
The form code looks something like this:

```
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//treat-candida.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6e792c187ee9f2f2ad&amp;id=787f11a" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
    <h2>Subscribe to our list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk"></span> </div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-EMAIL"><span class="asterisk"></span>
</label>
    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-FNAME"><span class="asterisk"></span>
</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="required" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>    
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_d6e792c187ee9f2f2da2f179d_787f1101bd" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';fnames[1]='FNAME';ftypes[1]='text';fnames[2]='COOKIE';ftypes[2]='text';fnames[3]='GENDER';ftypes[3]='text';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
```

What I have to do is to append values from the URL to `//treat-candida.us3.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=d6e792c187ee9f2f2ad&amp;id=787f11a`

 within the code. I tried using  and .innerHTML to edit just that part. It passes the values successfully that way, but the form won't be submitted properly because of the edit. It looks like I have to edit the whole code with divs and text at once. Is there an elegant way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Do something like:

```
$("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").action = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").action + values
```

Comment: It looks like values aren't getting passed this way

Comment: jQuery objects don't have an `action` property. You should be using `.attr()` to get and set attributes.

Comment: @Barmar, can you tell me how would the function look like with .attr?

Comment: `$("#mc-embeddeded-subscribe-form").attr("action", $("#mc-embeddeded-subscribe-form").attr("action")+values);`

Comment: @Barmar, thanks for the reply. I tried using the function, but it doesn't change the value.